# Unknown class from DLL

Tags: c++, qt, dll

I am new at creating DLL's and I am trying to get a class from my DLL.
But I keep getting errors that the class is unknown.
I am not use a header file.

I am trying to create a working app based on what is writen here: https://myprogrammingnotes.com/create-dll-qt.html

**DLL file**

```
    #ifndef DLLCLASS_H
    #define DLLCLASS_H
    //#include "dllclass_global.h"
    #if defined(DLLCLASS_LIBRARY)
    #  define DLLCLASSSHARED_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
    #  define DLLCLASSSHARED_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
    class DLLCLASSSHARED_EXPORT DllClass
    {
    public:
        DllClass();
        virtual ~DllClass();
        virtual bool fun(char *);
    };
    extern "C" DLLCLASSSHARED_EXPORT DllClass * getDllClass();
    typedef DllClass* (*GetDllClass)();
    #endif // DLLCLASS_H
```

**App file**

```
QLibrary mylib("mydll.dll");
if (!mylib.load())
{
    return;
}
GetDllClass  getDllClass = (GetDllClass)mylib.resolve("getGetDllClass");
if(!GetDllClass)
{
    return;
}
DllClass *dllclass = getDllClass();
dllclass->fun((char*)"hello");
```

**Errors**
[image]

**Question**
Why is the type unknown?
Is it not included when the DLL is loaded?

Comment: did you include the header file?

Comment: @user253751 No and i am not planning to use it.

Comment: So how should the compiler know what `GetDllClass` means, if you haven't told it?

Comment: @user253751 the class defined into the dll isn't that enough? what do i need to add tell the app what is means.

Comment: When the compiler compiles the app file, it doesn't know what's in the DLL. Isn't that the whole point? If you wanted it to know what was in the DLL, you would have included the header which tells it what's in the DLL.

Comment: @user253751 yes but still want to acces the class functions.

Comment: Forget the DLL for a moment. The compiler cannot see the DLL and it doesn't even know there is a DLL. Your app code says the word `GetDllClass`. How should the compiler know what the word `GetDllClass` means, if you haven't told it? Like if I write a program `int main() {Student s; cin >> s;}` the compiler will have no idea what `Student` means.

Comment: @user253751 without the DLL it does not know. Therefore you create a type def. But i the example the tho only type def is done in the DLL.

Comment: Why don't you create your own typedef? A typedef just says that a certain word means a certain type, by the way. It tells the compiler what a word means. But when the compiler compiles the code, it only looks at the type. The word doesn't get saved in the DLL file.

Comment: @user253751 do i need to typedef the whole class or only the functions that ia want to use?

Comment: If you want to use a word like `GetDllClass` the compiler has to know what that means. If you want to use `DllClass`, that's impossible because even if you tell the compiler about the class `DllClass` it won't know that it has to call myLib.resolve to find the functions. You would have to find a different way.

Comment: @user253751 Thank for the help, i am going to look for a other way to make it work.

Comment: @vincentpportvliet Note that calling a function from a DLL *is* possible. You *can* call getDllClass (but you need to write valid code and not just make up words without telling the compiler what they mean). The problem is the class. You can treat the `DllClass*` as a `void*`, and you can probably get the class functions using `mylib.resolve`, and you maybe can't actually call them in a way that works.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not use a header file.

You positively need definitions for the class (typically from a header file). There is no way the application can compile if it doesn't know what the class is.

There's ways to have a minimal class and hide details, but the class you're calling into must be known.

Comment: You don't need a header file, actually, just declarations.